# styles.css resource not loading when on the server, works locally

Tags: html, css

I'm new to creating webpages, so perhaps this is really easy and I just can't see it. I have a HTML/CSS template that I am modifying for a new site. When I check the index.html file locally (in Dreamweaver or in browsers) it appears correct. When I uploaded them to the server then the website does not load the images and it appears that the styles.css file is not loading correctly. I have attached a few screenshots to get the ball rolling. As always thanks for your assistance.

[image: index.html code]

[image: server folder structure]

[image: css folder structure]

Desired Output:
[image: What it looks like locally]

Current Output:
[image: What it looks like from the server]

Comment: Difficult to tell from this limited information. Possibly a file ownership/access right problem, I suggest you check your server logs for access errors

Comment: [No "_thanks_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) (at least in questions).

Comment: No code as image please.

Comment: @visibleman I checked the log and I get a status error 403 when trying to get the styles.css. I checked the permission on the styles.css and it is set to 700, which seems correct based on my limited subject knowledge.

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, I typically wouldn't attach code by a screenshot, but it was so little I thought it should be OK. I will not be so lazy in future.

Comment: @visibleman You were correct. I changed some of the folders to 755 from 705 and changed some of the files to 604. I am not 100% sure why that worked, so I will have to review permissions requirements. Thanks for the tip on checking the log. I really was thinking it was some kind of directory/path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely (later confirmed by asker in comment) a file and directory access right problem. 
This can be verified by checking the access logs of the http server.

The solution is to update the ownership and permissions of any problem files so that the http server has rights to them.  In this case, it is probably the easiest to examine the permissions of the index.html file and related folders and apply the same permission to the problematic files/folders.